# How do I solve this inconsistency with the silhouette scala library when discarding authenticators?

Tags: scala, race-condition, silhouette

I am using the [play-silhouette-library](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) version 2.0.2 for my authentication on my website.

Right now I have this method that activates when the user signs out:

```
def signOut(url: String) = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    val result = Future.successful(Redirect(url))
    env.eventBus.publish(LogoutEvent(request.identity, request, request2lang))
    request.authenticator.discard(result)
}
```

However, on Chrome only (not Firefox), the user fails to sign out about 40% of the time. I believed that this was due to some sort of race condition with the authenticator discard, so as a quick test I added `Thread.sleep(20)` before the authenticator discard:

```
def signOut(url: String) = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    val result = Future.successful(Redirect(url))
    env.eventBus.publish(LogoutEvent(request.identity, request, request2lang))
    Thread.sleep(20)
    request.authenticator.discard(result)
}
```

and the problem would not occur. However, adding a `Thread.sleep()` call isn't exactly production-ready code, so I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution.

I tried:

```
def signOut(url: String) = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    val publish = Future.successful(
      env.eventBus.publish(LogoutEvent(request.identity, request, request2lang))
    )
    Await.ready(publish, Duration.Inf)
    request.authenticator.discard(Future(Redirect(url)))
}
```

But that did not fix the issue. I am inexperienced with this kind of problem and would love some help.

Comment: The story you tell sounds strange to me. Do you handle `LogoutEvent` in your custom code in any way? Is the issue still reproducible if you move `Thread.sleep` **_before_** the `publish` call?

Comment: @SergGr, I don't use LogoutEvents anywhere else in our code, but interestingly a `Thread.sleep` before the publish call fixed the issue as well. I suppose that indicates some sort of conflict elsewhere?

Comment: Lukas, exactly! IMHO this test proves that if there is a concurrency conflict it is not within your `signOut` but with something else. It is hard to guess where from what I know now. Most probably the next step I'd try to investigate is what is the difference between Chrome and Firefox: analyze all requests around signout and their timings in both browsers to see if this is a race condition between processing two requests (and for example Firefox is not fast enough to issue two request concurrently).